# In .NET, how do I free memory for a 0-terminated unmanaged Unicode string, which was allocated by OLE?

Tags: .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, ole, unmanaged-memory

I obtain a pointer to a 0-terminated Unicode string in the [pwcsName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.statstg.pwcsname?view=netframework-4.8) field of the [STATSTG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.statstg?view=netframework-4.8) structure, by using the [IEnumSTATSTG::Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ienumstatstg-next) method.

The memory for it was allocated by OLE, but it is the caller's duty to free it.

I *assume* the memory was allocated using the unmanaged COM task memory allocator, but I could be wrong here. If the assumption is correct, I'd use `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(PtrToString)` to release that memory.

However, the argument is an `IntPtr`. In VB I tried to obtain an `IntPtr` with

```
PtrToString = CType(pwcsName, IntPtr)
```

The syntax is accepted, but the string is of wrong type (`Input string is not in a correct format.`)

Thus my questions:

How would I correctly obtain an `IntPtr` from the structure record's field?

Or more generally, how can I be the good citizen and prevent that potential memory leak?

---

This is the relevant code:

```
    Dim oElements As IEnumSTATSTG = Nothing
    oStorage.EnumElements(0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, oElements)

    Dim oElement(0) As Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.STATSTG
    Dim uiFetched As UInt32 = 0

    oElements.Next(1, oElement, uiFetched)
    Do While uiFetched > 0
        'Work with oElement(0).pwcsName

        'Attempt to free the memory occupied by the name.
        Dim pName As IntPtr
        pName = CType(.pwcsName, IntPtr)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pName)

        Yield ...
        oElements.Next(1, oElement, uiFetched)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the definition of [`STATSTG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-statstg) you'll read:

> `pwcsName`
> A pointer to a NULL-terminated Unicode string that contains the name. Space for this string is allocated by the method called and freed by the caller (**for more information, see CoTaskMemFree**).

So that memory must be freed by `CoTaskMemFree()` (`Marshal.CoTaskMemFree()` in .NET).

Depending on how you are marshaling the struct to .NET, it is possible that .NET will automatically free it. I say "depending" because you are referencing a version of `STATSTG` that has the `pwcsName` that is a `string`: in that case the .NET marshaller will free the `OLESTR`. If you use a `STATSTG` struct that uses an `IntPtr` then you'll have to call `CoTaskMemFree`.

To obtain a .NET `string` you can use `Marshal.PtrToStringUni()`.

Now... In your specific case, you are in a corner case. While on parameters of methods you can specify if they are `[In]` or `[Out]` to let the .NET Marshaller know when it has to "work" to Marshal the data (just before calling the method, or after calling the method, or both ways) (but I don't see them in your `Next()` definition), on single fields of structs I don't think you can (and then you can't surely modify `STATSTG`). So what happens here is that after a call to `Next()`, on the way C->.NET the .NET Marshaller will create a new `String` from the `OLESTR` and free the `OLESTR`. And we are happy. Then on the *next* call to `Next()`, before calling the actual API, the .NET Marshaller will see that there is a beautiful `String` in your struct and marshal it to an `OLESTR`, thinking it is data you want to pass to `Next()`. This is clearly useless. And now the problem: we don't know if the implementation of `Next()` will actually free this `OLESTR` before creating a new one for the next result (we could do some tests, but we don't want to). The easiest (and surest) solution is to set `pwcsName` to `Nothing` (`null` on C#) BEFORE EACH CALL TO `.Next()`. In this way the .NET Marshaller will see a beautiful `Nothing` and will marshal it to `null`. Less work done by the marshaller (marshalling strings is expensive), more safety for us that don't have to think if the `OLESTR` will be freed or not.

Post addendum: I've nugetted the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop 16.7.30328.74](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop/) and I've done a Go To Definition from a C# program. The method definition I see is different (and more detailed):

```
int Next([In][ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.ULONG")] uint celt, [Out][ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.STATSTG")][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] STATSTG[] rgelt, [ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.ULONG")] out uint pceltFetched);
```

I see that the `STATSTG[] rgelt` is marked as `[Out]`, so the marshalling will be done only in the C->.NET direction. You don't need to set to `Nothing`,

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, as laid out in the OP. However, `CoTaskMemFree` requires an `IntPtr`. I don't need an additional managed .NET string (which `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` would provide); I want to get rid of the existing OLE string. But without an `IntPtr` no call to `PtrToStringUni`, which I can't seem to obtain. I used `Dim oElement(0) As STATSTG` from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop`, and `oElements.Next(1, oElement, uiFetched)`

Comment: @Herb The signature of `IEnumSTATSTG::Next` you gave is C/C++, so you aren't using that. You are using a `static extern int Next(...)` that references a `STATSTG`. Paste both the `Next` method signature you are using and the `STATSTG` you are using. If `STATSTG` is already defined as a `string` then the .NET marshaller alread freed the string when it converted from the C/C++ `STATSTG` to the .NET `STATSTG`

Comment: Oh, I see, the string is ... managed after all?

I updated OP with the relevant VB code.

Comment: @Herb Yes, it should be. You haven't put the definition of `Next` and `STATSTG`. If you do a right click, Go to Definition you should be able to see them.

Comment: In `STATSTG` the definition for the name is `Public pwcsName As String`, it's in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop` as is also `Next`. `Next` is defined so (I hope the margin in this book is wide enough): `Function [Next](<ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.ULONG")> celt As UInteger, <ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.STATSTG")> rgelt() As STATSTG, <ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.ULONG")> ByRef pceltFetched As UInteger) As Integer`

Comment: @Herb A corner case... The truth is: **I don't know**... The good news is: **I have a sure solution**. Set to `Nothing` the `pwcsName` BEFORE each call to `.Next`. Why? Because the marshaller doesn't know the "direction" of the data, so when you call Next the marshaller will marshal .NET ->C your `STATSTG`, allocating a new OLE STR. Then, if you are lucky, `Next` (C side) will free the `pwcsName`, allocate a new `pwcsName` and pass it back. This if you are luck. But the API says that you should free it, and it doesn't expect to *receive* a OLESTR. It expects an empty struct. So set `Nothing`.

Comment: @Herb read the addendum and see if it is clear